# Where to put a function required by multiple pages that also requires the session information?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have this neat function defined in a .aspx.vb file, it requires the Session variable from the context to run. I guess I could just clone the function to the other .aspx.vb file where i need it too but is there like a higher place I can put it where it would be available to both page classes and I could still have the current session variables?

Comment: Pass the relevant information from the session as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the session from anywhere in your application without having to pass it or anything. Just fully qualify the session method.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session("MySessionVariable") = Something
```